# Is there a tool like `script` (Linux/Solaris/etc) for Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, terminal, script

Perhaps the worst-named tool in the *nix world, `script` is extremely handy when you want to capture all the output of a terminal session.

Is there a tool like it for Windows? Specifically, without having to install something like `cygwin`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows PowerShell has a `Start-Transscript` cmdlet.

Comment: very cool - does anything similar exist pre-Powershell? This is definitely going to be a boon :)

Comment: @warren:  Not that I know of and rarely needed. I only ever needed a log of batch files but those are trivial to do. Sessions ... not so much. Shouldn't be too hard writing a program that dumps the complete console log to a file afterwards, though.

Answer (score 2):

[MTee](http://www.commandline.co.uk/mtee/) is a tiny (11KB) program that works like the Unix `tee` command.
That is, it takes the output from a program (like cmd.exe) and sends it in two directions: to the console and to a file.

So you can use:

```
cmd.exe | mtee.exe C:\Path\some_log_file.txt
```